# Is it good practice to place a 'd' after the number on decimal numbers

Tags: java

So in the videos I'm using to learn java they place a 'f' after float (per java rules), and he tells you to place a  'd' behind a decimal number and I want to know if its a good practice to do so?

```
int myIntValue = 5;
float myFloatValue = 5f;
double myDoubleValue = 5d ;
System.out.println("myIntValue = " + myIntValue);
System.out.println("myFloatValue = " + myFloatValue);
System.out.println("myDoubleValue = " + myDoubleValue);
```

Comment: That is a **`double`** (not a *decimal*). And it is needed for `long` too (a `L` or `l`).

Comment: "Is it good practice" is surely a matter of opinion here.

Comment: @GalAbra OP's asking about `d` not the `f`.

Comment: Personally, I'd find it annoying to read lots of constants with a "d" suffix. I believe it is *always* redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` or `D` is not for "decimal" number, is for `double`. It's not necessary because every literal floating point number in Java is a double by default.

So, this:

```
double x = 5.0;
```

Will perform the same as this:

```
double x = 5d;
```

---

> I want to know if its a good practice to do so

It's not a matter of good practice or not. Most code I've read omits the `d` at the end. If you feel more comfortable using the `d` for your literal values, then it's ok too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you're not going to include the fractional part. `5` on its own is an [integer literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1), which is then promoted to `double`. `5d` is a [double literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2). You can also write `5.0`, which can't be an integer literal, and so is a floating-point literal.

From the second link above:

> **For decimal* floating-point literals, at least one digit** (in either the whole number or the fraction part) **and either a decimal point, an exponent, or a float** type suffix** are required. All other parts are optional. The exponent, if present, is indicated by the ASCII letter e or E followed by an optionally signed integer.

*(my emphasis)*

Then later

> A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter `D` or `d` (§4.2.3).

---

* Here they mean the number base (base 10), not a decimal *type*.

** Here they meant a floating point suffix, either `f`/`F` for `float` or `d`/`D` for `double`